# gotofile plugin not working on mac

Tags: sublime-text-2

I installed [go to file plugin for sublme text2](https://github.com/gs/sublime-text-go-to-file).
When I click `alt-d` it prints `∂` in editor and navigating to file not working.

[image: go to file plugin for sublme text2 not working]

I tried to change key bindings for this plugin but in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/GoToFile` I dont have key bindings file:

```
$ ls
README.md       go_to_file.pyc      repositories.json
go_to_file.py       package-metadata.json
```

So how to goto required file without copiing its name and navigating through `super+p`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to [add the keybindings to your own](https://github.com/gs/sublime-text-go-to-file#usage).

Go to the `User` package and add those lines to your `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap`:

```
{
  "keys": ["alt+d"], "command": "go_to_file"
},
{
  "keys": ["alt+i"], "command": "file_info"
}
```

If that file doesn't exist, create it and wrap the text above in square brackets.

---

Note that on OS X, pretty much every <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Letter key</kbd> combination is used for special characters, so you should probably add a `ctrl` or `super` to the shortcuts.